# Slider moving from left to right with border radius is not keeping border-radius

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

We have slider in one of our website http://deka.com.au/ , and we have added border-radius to slider, but when image slide, it remove border-radius bit ...

I tried to set parent with overflow - hidden, but i am not sure , why it is not working....

Comment: i see not least than 65 errors in console...

Comment: yeah i know it was becuase of other developer who is also working on that.. I already informed my client on that...

Comment: The border is being maintained, its just the white of the next slide coming over the corner momentarily.

Comment: then overflow hidden should not hide it... I think it should hide it...

Answer (score 0):

put some more effort,you could have mentioned the structure of your your slideshow or uploaded your html code,anyways it seems that you are trying to use list item with background image and  each image is having a href.

the problem may be--:

1. You have one main division(lets say scroll), which is having a width=sum of width of all the images.then you must be having a division which has a width=width of single image and that division must be having a property of overflow hidden and border radius. There might be some ***height*** related issues of division and check whether the scroll division is **enclosed** properly within the main division having overflow hidden property.*No possible solution can be ascertained unless you become more expressive with your code*.